# MySQL - Optimise user registration statistics query

Tags: php, mysql

Can any one instruct me on a more optimised way of querying this statistics of registered users, I currently lack the knowledge to create a better query. Right now it works fine, but I want to learn more about other ways to do the same thing and improve on it, this way I can expand my knowledge on MySQL, and study on other functions.

```
SELECT
  # Count users with complete profile registered current month and year
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE completed_registration = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ) AS completed_0,

  # Count users with complete profile registered 1 month ago
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE completed_registration = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ) AS completed_1,

  # Count users with complete profile registered 2 months ago ( this is repeated 3 more times but for the sake of brevity is not here)
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE completed_registration = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) ) AS completed_2,

  # Count users with incomplete profile and verified email registered current month and year
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE completed_registration = 0 AND verified_email = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) ) AS incomplete_0,

  # Count users with incomplete profile and verified email registered 1 month ago
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE completed_registration = 0 AND verified_email = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) ) AS incomplete_1,

  # Count users with incomplete profile and verified email registered 2 month ago ( this is repeated 3 more times but for the sake of brevity is not here)
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE completed_registration = 0 AND verified_email = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) ) AS incomplete_2,

  # Count users with unverified email registered current month and year
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE verified_email = 0 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) ) AS unverified_0,

  # Count users with unverified email registered 1 month ago
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE verified_email = 0 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) ) AS unverified_1,

  # Count users with unverified email registered 2 month ago ( this is repeated 3 more times but for the sake of brevity is not here)
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE verified_email = 0 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) ) AS unverified_2,

  # Count all registered users
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users ) AS total_users,

  # Count all complete profiles
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE completed_registration = '1' ) AS total_registered_users,

  # Count all incomplete profiles
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE verified_email = 1 AND completed_registration = 0 ) AS total_incomplete_users,

  # Count all users with unverified email
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE verified_email = '0' ) AS total_unverified_users
```

In the same query it counts information from other tables related to the users for example, in another `SELECT` subquery it joins the profile_type table to count how many are registered as teachers or interpreters or translators.

Comment: This doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, this question belongs on [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Understood, I expanded the question on [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in case you have some time to check it out here is the expanded [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77466/mysql-optimise-web-panel-users-statistics-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit your table muliple times so no wonder its slow:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN completed_registration = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS completed_0,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed_registration = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS completed_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed_registration = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS completed_2,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed_registration = 0 AND verified_email = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomplete_0,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed_registration = 0 AND verified_email = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomplete_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed_registration = 0 AND verified_email = 1 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomplete_2,
SUM(CASE WHEN verified_email = 0 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unverified_0,
SUM(CASE WHEN verified_email = 0 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unverified_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN verified_email = 0 AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unverified_2,
COUNT(*) AS total_users,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed_registration = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_registered_users,
SUM(CASE WHEN  verified_email = 1 AND completed_registration = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_incomplete_users,
SUM(CASE WHEN verified_email = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS total_unverified_users
FROM users
```

Comment: Thank you @mihai! I tried your solution and it didn't work at first, then found out that it has to be `SUM` instead of `CASE`. Please edit the answer.

Comment: Damn,COUNT doesnt work in this situation it has to be SUM,COUNT also counts the 0